# Drupal Views taxonomy hierarchy

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I´ve got a problem with how to display taxonomy terms of node with which I need some help.

I´ve got 2 taxonomy vocabularies: categories and featured article. The first is a hierarchical vocabulary in which terms can be nested on multiple levels. The featured article vocabulary only has a YES term.

Now in my View I want to display my nodes which have featured article set to YES in random fashion. This I have managed to do.

Now besides the teaser and title, I would also like to display every category of the node, nested like this:

Parent > Child > ChildOfChild

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by every category of the node?

Comment: every term from the vocabulary "category"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting the Taxonomy: All terms fields with the limit the terms by vocabulary option did the job. It didn´t work before cause I only selected the child category for the node. I have to selecte both the parent and child categories.

Comment: although this shows them both, it´s still not ideal. 1. you must check the parent category 2. if checked in the wrong order they will appear in the wrong order

Comment: second problem seems to be solved using taxonomy term weight.